# Please Help with Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have 3 columns, that if they all have certain values, I increase the value of calculated column by 1. So if the value of the calculated column `=3`, then I want the column to equal true. But there is one caveat, if the first column has one of two different values then I want the calculated column to also equal true without any other conditions needed.

Here is my sample code:

```
IF(IF(OR[Data Classification Type]="Confidential","Pii","Ephi", 1,0)+IF(OR[Data Transfer Type]="internal Email","Internal Network","Secure Mail","FileCloud Secure Transfer","Secure Flash Drive","SFTP - SSH", 1,0)+IF(OR[Data Storage Type]="Internal Database","External Database - Encrypted","FileCloud","Issued Laptop","SharePoint","Secure Flash Drive","Locked File Cabinet","Locked office", 1,0)=3, IF(OR[Data Classification Type]="public","De-identified data"), "Yes","No")
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Used a little different approach (using AND/OR) to accomplish the same requirements (if I understood it correctly).

Update the following formula with the **column names** and **values** in your list as required (I've used fewer column values for this example).

```
=IF(OR(ClassType="Public",ClassType="De-identified data"),"Yes",IF(AND(OR(ClassType="Confidential",ClassType="Pii",ClassType="Ephi"),OR(TransferType="internal Email",TransferType="Internal Network",TransferType="Secure Mail"),OR(StorageType="Internal Database",StorageType="External Database - Encrypted",StorageType="FileCloud")),"Yes","No"))
```

[image]

Comment: that did it... you the bomb.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you. Please mark the question as answered if it helped you

Comment: new issue:   this works fine for new entries, but if I edit an existing entry it does not update. any thoughts?

Comment: It should work for editing as well. I think, there might be some mismatched values in your formula. Calculated columns should work the same way for both the adding and editing actions. I would suggest testing with fewer values in the formula first and then add all of your values once your test is passed. You could post your formula and let me know when it's not working, I can take a look.